# Importing issues from Maya 2015 to 2017

Tags: maya

I tried to import a scene (it was a glock model) from 2015 to 2017, however for some reason, the grip of the gun is all messed up: as seen with the first image. [image] Is it a problem with the gun itself or is it an importing problem? Also here was the original model back in Maya 2015: [image]

Answer (score -1):

have you tried to freeze and reset transformations and delete history (delete by type -> history) while in Maya 2015? That's just a guess, but it helped when I had kinda similar problem.